# Child facial image dataset

Tags: faces

I am looking for a face-image dataset of children. I have found one for facial expression: [CAFE - The Child Affective Face Set](https://www.childstudycenter-rutgers.com/). Another possibility is to use an AGE based dataset, such as [Large Age-Gap](http://www.ivl.disco.unimib.it/activities/large-age-gap-face-verification/), and keep only the child images. However, I would like to know if there is any other complete and better dataset.

A possible use of this database is to develop child identity recognition, such as [this one](http://discovery.dundee.ac.uk/portal/en/theses/facial-identification-of-children(03679266-9552-45da-9c6d-0f062c4893c8).html).

Comment: I wonder if you have found any other datasets? I am doing research on Facial Recognition on children!

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. It was for a colleague, who later created a small dataset by himself.